# Iterating Through Array of Objects - Python Hash Table

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, object, hashtable

I'm trying to make my own Hash Table class in Python. I have a class for my HashEntry (acts as a private inner class) and a class for the HashTable itself. I am using numpy object arrays for this.

When I attempt to implement my "remove" method, I need to be able to find the hashEntry in the hashArray by its key. This means I have to iterate through the hashEntry ojects in the hashArray, and access each 'key' attribute for 'entry'. When I run the code, I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'key'

How can I iterate through a numpy object array, and access each of their attributes? Or did I set something up wrong?
My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

class HashEntry():
    def __init__(self, inKey="", inValue=None): #sets default values if not specified
        self.key = inKey
        self.value = inValue
        self.state = 1 # 0 = never used, 1 = used, -1 = formerly used

    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.key + " -> " + str(self.value))

class DSAHashTable():
    def __init__(self, tableSize):
        self.count = 0
        self.actualSize = self.findNextPrime(tableSize)            # Set table size
        self.hashArray = np.empty([self.actualSize, 1], dtype=object) #Initialize hashArray

    def put(self, inKey, inValue):
        newEntry = DSAHashEntry(inKey, inValue)
        idx = self.hashFunction(inKey)
        self.hashArray[idx] = newEntry
        self.count += 1

    def remove(self, inKey):
        for entry in self.hashArray:
            if entry.key == inKey:
                np.delete(self.hashArray, inKey)
                self.count -= 1

table = DSAHashTable(150)
table.put("a", "sock")
table.put("b", "shoes")
table.remove("a")
```

For context, 'findNextPrime' is just class function to get the next prime number after the one given. (not relevant)

Answer (score 0):

When you make an array like

```
np.empty([self.actualSize, 1], dtype=object)
```

and then iterate with

```
for entry in self.hashArray:
```

Look at what `entry` is.  Don't assume - verify.

I don't think using an object array instead of a list has any advantage.  Except for a few indexing tasks, using an object array is slower.  I (and others) have discussed this lots of times on SO (though I'm not sure there's an easy way to find such answers).

Comment: I would use a list however I need to implement functionality where a maximum capacity for the array can be declared. For example, in this instance, the table should have a capacity of 151 (next prime after 150)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've discovered the issue. My object array wasn't full, and thus had null elements. This means my iterator works, but since it passes through the null elements, it gives the error.

To fix, I put an *if* just under my for loop

```
if entry is not None:
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future